# Automatic function signature and call changing and refactoring in C code base

Tags: c, refactoring, clion, signature

I have found that in CLion it is possible to change functions signature, e.g. parameters' number and/or order alongside with the all places where it is called from. However it allows to do it only from a dialog window and in one-by-one manner, as far as I understood. Is there a way to write a script which will do this for all signatures and calls taken from the script or kind of input data? In other words I want to find a way to quickly refactor all code base having slightly changed something in the "task" script. I mean to modify the refactoring from time to time in one place/file and run it against all code base. Otherwise it is a lot of manual work even for one refactoring concept. But what if it is changed everyday. Here is how it is done in Clion in a one-by-one manner.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Refactorings__Change_Signature.html

Comment: I can't speak to CLion specifically, but it sounds like you are looking for something more like a code generator.  That would be a separate program or script you write that generates the wanted C source code.  Often such things take a template-based approach.

Comment: Alternatively, you might be able to find a macro-based approach that would amount to a similar thing.

Comment: [coccinelle](https://coccinelle.gitlabpages.inria.fr/website/)?